# getting HttpResponseMessage from a Task<HttpResponseMessage>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-web-api

Inside HttpClient using statement I need to unwrap from somewhere HttpResponseMessage.

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
     client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authUser);
     Task<HttpResponseMessage> m = client.GetAsync(url);   
     // HttpResponseMessage msg = ???              
     task.Wait();
     return task.Result;
}
```

my question is: how can I get HttpResponseMessage from this line

```
Task<HttpResponseMessage> m = client.GetAsync(url);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should [`await`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156528.aspx) the task:

```
HttpResponseMessage m = await client.GetAsync(url);
```

In order to do that, the calling method needs to be marked `async`.

Answer (score 0):

To get HttpResponseMessasge you should use Task.Result property.
Here is your code (a bit modified) with HttpResponseMessage got from Task:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authUser);
    Task<HttpResponseMessage> task = client.GetAsync(uri);
    **HttpResponseMessage msg = task.Result;**
    task.Wait();
    return task.Result;
}
```

Comment: This is quite often a very bad idea: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html